# Correct way to apply corrections to bugs when the repo is pushed already

Tags: git

I have the following situation in a repo of mine

[image]

As you can see the main branch, the develop branch are both pushed to remote branches. The Feature branch is also pushed but there are some commits that are still local.

While doing that I realized that a script had a bug since the very beginning. I wanted to correct this bug *in the main branch* so I created a bug correction branch and I corrected it.

That is the situation. But how should I proceed from here?

I thought of merging the bug correction to main and pushing main so that the remote has the corrected version in main, but then...

- should I rebase develop to the new main? If so how does this affect the remote develop?
- or should I rebase Feature to the new main? (but then how does this affect develop? and the remotes?)
- or should I merge Feature into develop and rebase this one (and forget about Feature) but then how does this affect remote develop

The goal is to have the develop branch with the bug corrected (and eventually I am going to merge Feature into develop too)

Comment: You can merge the hotfix (`correctedBug`) into both `develop` and `feature`, that's entirely fine.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you based branches on a branch (in your case `feature` on `dev`) you should never rebase that base branch (in your case `dev`) because then all your child branches (in your case `feature`) will become detached and merging them becomes a "bit" painful. Not impossible but you should avoid it if possible ;)

To avoid unnecessary work **don't** rebase `dev` on the bug-fixed `main`.

In general, the clean version in your case would be:

1. create `bugfix` branch from `dev`
2. merge `bugfix` to `dev`
3. merge `bugfix` to `main`
4. merge `dev` to `feature`, or rebase `feature` on `dev`

If `dev` already contains commits you don't want to merge to `main`. You have to create the bugfix branch from `main`. Then you end up in the same situation you are in at the moment.

**How to proceed in your situation**

Merge the changes from `main` to `dev`. If you want to be done with all the merging for this you should merge `dev` into `feature` or rebase, `feature` on the new bug fixed `dev` depending on your preferences.

You would have to do that for all `feature-x` branches created from `dev` before the `bugfix` merge. But you don't have to do that right now. You can do that just before merging the `feature` branch back to `dev`.

```
git switch dev
git merge main
git switch feature
```

Merge version (recommended version)

```
git merge dev
```

Rebase version (advanced version if you know what you are doing)

```
git rebase dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I mostly agree with @sfeldmann's answer but want to give you an additional suggestion.

Once your problem is solved, you may think about optimizing your git-workflow to avoid such "problems" in the future.

I would reccommend you the feature-branch workflo. With it you have an always shippable product on master and do your increments with feature/bugfix/hotfix-branches in a very generic manner.
It also scales with more team-mates and CI/CD if you want to have it in the future.

Check it out on: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow.
Or if it doesn't fit your use-case you maybe want to have a look on the git workflow-comparsion by atlassian: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand this is just a case of parallel development. `develop` and
`feature` are happening (relative to `main`) at the same time as
`bugfix`. Then the answer to what to merge what and where is the same as
if we were talking about `feature1`, `feature2`, and `feature3`: pick a
workflow about where features (and bugfixes) go and stick to it. Maybe
they are branched from `develop` and merged into it. (I have no idea what
`develop` is about here and I won’t make assumptions.)

On the other hand this is a bug fix. And sometimes you may have to think
about where to fix a bug:

- Bug was introduced on `feature`: fix it there (there is nowhere else to
  fix it)
- Bug was introduced on `main` lately: fix it there so that all the eight
  parallel feature branches can make use of it (I guess this is your
  answer in this case?)
- Bug was introduced on `support-v3.1`, which is a branch for version 3.1
  (you are currently on version 5.2): fix it on that branch and then
  cascade-merge the fix down to the main branch (`main` or `develop`
  perhaps). By cascade-merge I mean to merge it into all the version
  branches one by one until you reach the main branch.

Bug fixing in Git, in my opinion, should happen at some point where you
can eventually merge the change to all places where you need it; you
should try to avoid the pattern of fixing something on the latest version
and then figuring out a week later that you need the fix on version 3.1 as
well, which forces you to then make a cherry-pick commit on *that*
branch. Because with cherry-pick commits it becomes hard to keep track of
what fixes have been applied where.

If you merge your bug fix to all necessary branches you just need

```
git branch --contains=<bug fix commit>
```

In order to find all branches that have it.

With cherry-pick fixes you have to make up some identifier to find them
all. Like an issue key.

All of that said though: most bug fixes are just done on the main
branch. If you then use *GitHub Flow* you do:

- Check out `main` (or `develop`: the main code branch)
- Make `bugfix` from `main`
- Fix it
- “Merge” it somehow (squash merge, true merge, rebase, cherry-pick…) into `main`

And how the other parallel branches are then updated is dictated by the
workflow that you are following.